# Integrate existing cassandra data to elassandra

Tags: java, elasticsearch, cassandra, jhipster, elassandra

Is there any way to intigrate existing cassandra cluster link with the elassandra running instance.We have lot's of data in the existing cassandra cluster and when we intigrate my application with elassandra its work well but my existing data is not there to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with it. The problem was at the time to configuration of elissandra.

have you use: `nodetool rebuild <source-datacenter-name>`?